# TestRail API returned HTTP 429("API Rate Limit Exceeded - 180 per minute maximum allowed. Retry after 1 seconds.")

Tags: testrail

Getting error message while doing automation parallel execution with TestRail integration as below -

```
TestRail API returned HTTP 429("API Rate Limit Exceeded - 180 per minute maximum allowed. Retry after 1 seconds.")
```

Ideally, it would be very difficult to manage testrail to log all execution details when we choose parallel execution.

Comment: Not sure what your question is - it's a normal behavior of TestRail cloud, which is described in their docs - http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/introduction (see last section)

Answer (score 1):

What you could try as an alternative is to aggregate some of the results up and post them in batches.

http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/reference-results#add_results_for_cases

It will allow you to attach multiple results for a test run at the same time. So you could group all results in the teardown fixture of a class or a full suite of tests and post all results.

Would that help?

Comment: Nope, I'm really sorry. if automation test suite aborted in the middle of execution we'll lot all test results logging to testRail. Assume that we have 1000+ test scripts and 500 had an execution and suddenly it got aborted due to unexpected interruption.

Comment: Even if 500 had executed and it cut off there, you would still have the results for 490+ depending on how many tests you had per file, before the exception happened.